# Links not clickable because of z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a div with absolute position on a page which overlaps on another div when scrolling. I want to make it invisible when it scrolls to a specific div.

For that purpose, I'm using the `z-index`. I'm setting the `z-index` 1 of the div which I want to hide, and much higher `z-index` for the other div. However it does not hide the div. If I set the `z-index` to -1 then it hides but then the links on that div are no more clickable. How can I fix this?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.up {
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.down {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 200;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="up">
    <div class="box"><a href="#">Should hide</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="down">Should be visible</div>
</div>
```

So the problem in above example is that the links in the .box are not clickable (because of -ve `z-index` value), and if I set it positive, it wont hide behind the .down.

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/G2xRA/

Comment: How to used z-index read this blog http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually `z-index` only works with `position` so I gave the `position:relative;` to your `.down` class.

See the mentioned below **CSS** & **DEMO**.

```
.box{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        background: yellow;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        z-index: 1;  
    }

    .down {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 green;
        height: 400px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xRA/4/)

Answer (score 12):

In order for z-index's to go on top of each other you will both elements to have positioned.

A better description:

> Definition and Usage
>
> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

So you will need:

```
.up {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem too. I solved it by changing the **z-index** values with a value greater than -1.

I made the front layer 2 and behind 1, so it worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;  
}

.down{
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 400px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Make these 2 changes in the classes. Z-index won't work in .down as you didn't put position. And, there is no need for the -ive z-index in .box. Z-index works like layers, an element with z-index 1 will be under any element that has higher z-index than 1. Ofcourse for this to work the elements need to be positioned.