# Click through div with relative position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've trying to create a "window" to a fixed div below that contains a link.

Right now I have two divs with relative positions. The top div (red) is acting empty "window" to the fixed content underneath and the second (blue) will hold more page content.

I've looked for some answers and came across pointer-events:none; which works if the top divs are fixed, but fails when they are changed to relative.

This is the code for the div above the link:

```
#spacer-block{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity:.4;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bbpvf8d/) showing the issue

Looking for any suggestions. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you just want the link to be clickable? If so, why are you adding `z-index: -1;` to the `#window-space` div? Apologies if I’m not understanding the question correctly.

Comment: probably a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798446/links-not-clickable-because-of-z-index

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what you are actually trying to accomplish with Jquery. Are you trying to make a div set behind another "clickable" when an event occurs?

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch Thanks that link did it! Didn't do exactly what I wanted, but worked with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your problem.

```css
#top-content{
  position:reletive;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:blue;
}
#window-space{
 position:fixed;
 top:60px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#spacer-block{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display:block;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity:.4;
  background-color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
 }
 
 #window-space h2{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
   padding-top: 15%;
}
 
#window-inner{
 display: table;
 width: 56%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div id="window-space"><div id="window-inner"><h2><a href="#">This is where I want to click</a></h2></div></div>
<div id="spacer-block"></div>
<div id="top-content">

</div>
```